# Filter Product by Category

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WSGP.gif) When a user clicks a category it moves to another page and should show items by category. I'm new to Angular. using restful API.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your method of navigation to the next screen, you can fetch the details of the category that was initially tapped.

In the ngOnInit() for the second screen, you should fetch/filter data based on that category.

Comment: Can u give me a sample. bcz I'm totally new to Angular